# How JOIN Seq with Array in Clojure?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, clojure, seq

I would try to perform a SQL JOIN like on results from MongoDB.
I have data to show on grid:

```
seqgroup: ({:_id #<ObjectId 54db3ba76a5b2d5de2e7e990>, :group_name gr1, :usersingroup_id [#<ObjectId 54d1e37a2039b30a00b342ca> #<ObjectId 54d8ab240e81f5d1cbf6f691>]}
           {:_id #<ObjectId 54db46ba6a5b2d5de2e7e992>, :group_name gr2, :usersingroup_id [#<ObjectId 54d8af860e81f5d1cbf71da3> #<ObjectId 54d8ab240e81f5d1cbf6f691>]})
```

Instead of ObjectId for :usersingroup_id I would like to show user name that I keep in different collection with returns array :

```
get-one-user-byid:  {:_id #<ObjectId 54d1e37a2039b30a00b342ca>, :id someuser1}
get-one-user-byid:  {:_id #<ObjectId 54d8ab240e81f5d1cbf6f691>, :id someuser2}
```

How I would walk/get/conj/?? or anything else to have seq that contains usernames not ObjectId?

```
seqresultgroup: ({:_id #<ObjectId 54db3ba76a5b2d5de2e7e990>, :group_name gr1, :usersingroup_id [someuser1 someuser2]}
           {:_id #<ObjectId 54db46ba6a5b2d5de2e7e992>, :group_name gr2, :usersingroup_id [someuser3 someuser2]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try something like this.. We map an anonymous function over the seq of groups that updates the vector of user ID's to a vector of usernames. The `userids->usernames` function maps an anonymous function that pulls out the `:id` from the result of your `get-one-user-byid` function over the vector of ids. This results in the `:usersingroupid` vector of each group map getting set to a vector of user ID's.

```
(defn userids->usernames [id-coll]
      (map #(:id (get-one-user-byid %)) id-coll))

(map #(assoc % :usersingroup_id (userids->usernames (:usersingroupid %))) seqgroup)
```

1. `#(assoc % :usersingroup_id ...)`

   - The anonymous function above is "mapped" over the list of "group" maps you call `seqgroup`. This function will take each of the group maps, `%`, change the value of the key `:usersingroup_id` to the result of calling `userids->usernames` with the value of the key `:usersingroup_id` in the given group map as an argument.
2. `userids->usernames`

   - This function takes the vector of group IDs, and maps an anonymous function over it. The anonymous function uses your `get-one-user-byid` function to turn the `:_id` of a user, `%`,  into a user map. We extract the `:id` from the user map by simply wrapping `(get-one-user-byid %)` in `(:id ...)`

Comment: I am away from my computer and cannot test the code right now, but I will double check the code in an hour or so.

Comment: Looks incredibly mysteriously for my human being. I will test it in the morning with a pleasure.

Comment: Obviously it works. I just need to turn:         `clojure.lang.LazySeq@74468e66` into something more friendly to show in `html`. For now I will do `(pr-str (map #(:id (db/get-one-user-byid-grid %)) id-coll))`